# Grab input value after send key and console log the value Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently working on a project where I need to integrate the use of the Selenium Webdriver. I am using the Chrome implementation of Web Driver and running it via Javascript. I am currently testing a simple quantity input form. I am having trouble with a particular aspect of this project and that is ... I need the test to run through the form and put in different values everytime. I am placing the values via the sendKeys function. Now the trouble starts here... I need to grab the value that the sendKeys function inputs into the field and console.log a message depending on the value.

If the value is over a 100 I need the test to console.log the message "Exceeds 100".

If the value is less than 0 I need it to console.log the message "Below 0".

And if there is no value I need it to console.log the message "No input".

It runs through and puts in new values just fine. But the issue has been grabbing the value and console.logging a message depending on the value. I've tried many different options but there's just so little documentation related to this exact topic. I will link my code below, and I appreciate any input you guys may have... because it has me stumped unfortunately.

Also I am curious if this can be done using assertions in any way...

Test File Below:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89a84dbc15ba4088719400be1f359045

Answer (score 0):

There is a method **getAttribute(String attrName)** it will accept a string parameter, pass attribute name against which value got set.
for example:

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement("your unique element locator");
String valueText=element.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: I've tried that it usually gives me an unidentified error or a Promise { <pending> } error... I'm new to Selenium so I don't know if I'm implementing it wrong or what...

Comment: @MXM97 Selenium is simply browser automation tools which can only interact with element which is available in DOM as i can see there is  no attribute getting set  with your value.

Answer (score 0):

about the answer above me - you should try adding a .getText(), So the attribute value would become a String.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement("your unique element locator");
String valueText = element.getAttribute("value").getText();
```

Please add the full error message, A screenshot of the console would be good.

Comment: Alright, but how would I implement this in my code that I pasted in the above link. I'm brand new to Selenium so I don't even know where I would implement your code...